# Can a Schema use it's own model to validate?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

For example, say I have a user schema, and I want to validate that the username is unique before even attempting to save the user to the database.

```
...

UserSchema.path('username')
  .validate(function (value, respond) {
    User.findOne({ username: this.username }) // This isn't valid.
      .lean()
      .select('_id')
      .exec(function (err, user) {

        if (err) {
          winston.warn('User_username: Error looking for duplicate users');
          respond(false);
        }

        // If a user was returned, then the user is non-unique!
        if (user) {
          respond(false);
        }

        respond(true);
      });
  });

...

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I know I could use `mongoose.model('User').findOne(...)` but that just seems a bit silly, is there no better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an unique index in your schema by setting `unique: true`. This will make use of the unique index option that is available in mongodb. Here is an example snippet from one of my models using this option:

```
// The (generated) uniform resource locator
url: {
    // ... which is required ...
    required: true,
    // ... which is an unique index ...
    unique: true,
    // ... and is a string.
    type: String
}
```

**Compound key from comments:**

```
Schema.index({ username: 1, accountCode: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Comment: My example was simplified somewhat; I actually have two properties that, when combined, need to be unique. A `username` and a `accountCode`, so that a username is unique on the account it's tied too. Also, will the method you described return a `ValidationError`? Or a `MongoError`?

Comment: You can create compound indexes to do multiple field unique validation like this:

`Schema.index({ username: 1, accountCode: 1 }, { unique: true })`

It does however throw a MongoError, and not a ValidationError

Comment: Yeah, that's my issue, I've already created a compound index on the Schema, but I think there's a benefit in me validating that there isn't a duplicated entry prior to the save.

Comment: @matthewtole has the correct way for compound keys. There is no real benefit to doing your own validation other than having a more graceful error message, but concurrency can still trap you in the mongodb error. Added benefit is not there. :)